# Initializing char buffer in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, initialization, default-value

I am writing application on c++ and using intel inspector to do memory profiling.

However i have a question about the various results that i got during my memory profiling test for finding potential memory problems.

I am trying to do a better stable application and i have few questions I know they are basics still at this time looking too much into the code i am kind of confused. Thank you for the help in getting them clarfied.

1. should i initialize char buffer[30] to a default value ?
2. what should be the default vaue for the LPWSTR (I tried NULL) still it complains uninitialized memory access on my member variable.
3. Initialize a struct. I tried using memset. Still the profiler looks unhappy and complains uninitialized memory access.

One instance is 
In my caller class constructor i have initialized the handle as

```
m_hidHandle = NULL; //member variable and an object of struct hid_device
```

After which i make a call to do hid_write.

And in there, hid_write which inturns calls writeFile (this is the api class hid.c)

```
WriteFile(dev->device_handle, buf, length, NULL, NULL);
```

Here i get a complain that uninitialized memory access.
I even tried checking the api documentation for WrtieFile. Still unclean what i am making it to complain about
a memory problem.

Another instance is 
I have a member variable

```
WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG m_pConfig;
```

In the constructor, I am trying to initialize the struct to NULL:

```
memset( &m_pConfig, 0, sizeof(WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG) );
```

It complained uninitialized memory access. I even tried

```
//proxyConfig.fAutoDetect = false;
//proxyConfig.lpszAutoConfigUrl = NULL;
//proxyConfig.lpszProxy = NULL;
//proxyConfig.lpszProxyBypass = NULL;
```

Still no help.

Comment: Can you post some of your code that demonstrates what you're doing and the lines that throw the profiler errors?

Comment: i have added them to the initial posting. Thanks!!!

Comment: @linuxdeveloper, Just wondering, where's the `LPWSTR` (and `WriteFile`) coming from? I know of no such things in Linux, but it seems the `hid_device` you use is, unless you defined it locally in your application.

Comment: yes they are not used in the linux kernel. instead by the host application which is built using vc++

Answer (score 4):

1: Use `std::string` and it will be default-initialized:

```
std::string s; //empty
```

Otherwise, `char s[30] = {};` will fill it with 0s. `std::string` is much, much better for a stable application. If you need the C string to pass to an API, use `c_str()` to get a constant version. If you need a non-constant version, plop it into a vector of characters (which can be initialized with two iterators) and pass either `&v[0]` or `v.data()`.

2: `NULL` should work, as it's a `wchar_t *` (assuming the Windows API data type). If you have C++11, use `nullptr` instead.

3: `memset` is a terrible idea for any non-POD class. If you don't have a constructor, a default constructor will be provided for you that default-initializes all of the non-trivially constructible members. It's better to put in your own if you have members such as `int`, which would otherwise remain uninitialized:

```
struct S {
    int i;
    std::string s; //non-trivially constructible, so default-initialized
};

S s;
```

In the above example, you'll get an empty string and uninitialized `int`. That's why your own is usually better:

```
S() : i(), s() {}
```

Comment: Hmm why not v.front()? that's always what I've used.